# bootstrap asp.net--Not working in Clients

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have developed a asp.net website(.aspx) using the bootstrap and the total look and alignments were good while debugging the code in my local system using IE10.
once the code is deployed in a asp.net server the button styles and the alignments of the controls in html table tags  were totally different from the local site .

Please share your ideas for resolving the issue.

I have used the below tags in the master page.

```
<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.css" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />.
```

.
.
.
.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script  src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

thanks.

Comment: Check on production site what's the url used to get the resources using the browser developer tools. Is the one that you expect?

Comment: May be a virtual path problem. Try prepending url with `~/` like: `<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: use something like this  @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.css")

Comment: You need to include the IIS version you are deploying to

Comment: I have tried prepending the link href to "~/" but it didn't worked either and have used only the Min versions of bootstrap.

and in the production URL we are using IIS7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue got resolved.

all the resources were linked correctly but the issue was due to the default  browser version the pages are getting rendered.

So I needed to add the below the meta tag in the master page. After which all the pages were loading fine.

[link] meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

Thank you all for the suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need both versions of bootstrap.css - for production server use the minified version(s).

For example:

In your master page:

```
<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

In your Bundle.Config.cs class:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
                "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")); 
}
```

As regards setting the correct path in master page, this is a known bug and an easy way to get it right is to drag the CSS file from VS Solution Explorer to the head section of your master page in code view.

Comment: I have tried using only the minified versions for the master page and even tried dragging the css file from SE but it didn't worked.